# phpmyadmin login should not expire on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, security, ubuntu-10.04

On ubuntu 10.04 the phpmyadmin config is a little bit scattered.

I want to set the loginexpiration time to zero, should never expire, this is a secured setup behind a firewall. I think it is 3600 by default but cannot find the setting.

Where is it?

*Edit:* I actually changed it in /etc/phpmyadmin/conf.inc.php which seems the recommended place for ubuntu. The other files mentioned below might be overwritten on updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you want to change the value of `LoginCookieValidity`. This is defined and set in  `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/config.default.php` e.g.

`$cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = 1440;`

The documentation ( `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/Documentation.html` ) says this

> $cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] integer
>   [number of seconds]
>       Define how long is login cookie valid. Please note that php
>   configuration option
>   session.gc_maxlifetime might limit
>   session validity and if session is
>   lost, login cookie is also
>   invalidated. So it is good idea to set
>   session.gc_maxlifetime at least as
>   high is $cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] is
>   set.